Asyncio call returns JSONDecodeError
I am fairly new to API world and Python. I am trying to make asynchronous call to an API which ran fine in VSCode IDE but gives me issues when I try to run on a Linux environment. I keep getting an json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error. Python version is 3.11 and Linux is Red Hat 8.5
The code that I am trying to run is as follows:
#Define Global Variables
emp_ids = []
response_results = []

#Data pull
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Successfully connected to UKG API: Status Code {response.status_code}")
    logger.info('Successfully connected to UKG API: Status Code {}'.format(response.status_code))
    

    def get_tasks(session):
        tasks = []
        for emp_id in emp_ids:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(baseURL+f"personnel/v1/user-defined-fields?employeeId={emp_id}", headers=headers)))
        return tasks

    start_time = time.time()

    async def get_data():
        session_timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=1800)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=session_timeout) as session:
            tasks = get_tasks(session)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            for response in responses:
                response_results.append(await response.json(content_type=None))
                
    
    asyncio.run(get_data())

    end_time = time.time()
    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"It took {total_time} seconds to make {len(emp_ids)} API Calls")
    logger.info("It took {} seconds to make {} API Calls".format(total_time,len(emp_ids)))**

#Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pentaho/pdi/Scripts/Python/UKG/UKG_Employee_User_Defined.py", line 103, in <module>
    asyncio.run(get_data())
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pentaho/pdi/Scripts/Python/UKG/UKG_Employee_User_Defined.py", line 101, in get_data
    response_results.append(await response.json(content_type=None))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1120, in json
    return loads(stripped.decode(encoding))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/zmadni/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I had to add content_type=None to make this run in Linux as without it the async call would get stuck and not return anything until 30 min timeout expires. The odd thing is that this Error does not shows up randomly meaning there are days where the script runs fine without any issues.

Have you tried printing the response and checking that it was valid and actually contains JSON?

@MarkTolonen So i did check the response and it was as follows:
<CIMultiDictProxy('Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'Content-Length': '3453', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', >
Does this mean i should update my "Content Type" argument in the for loop?

Of responses that was the response that failed?  What are the first few bytes of response.content?  That will show what triggered the failure

@MarkTolonen Sorry getting back to this after a while. I am not sure how to implement "response.content" in my code? if you are able to write it out for me i would appreciate it.

print((response.content[:20].hex()) to dump the hexadecimal value of the first 20 bytes.

Sorry a little late coming back to this, but I figured out the issue. Turns out i was trying to call API end point during application maintenance time. Thanks for the help!
